# cannot retrieve the selected java filename/path in eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

I am developing a plugin that requires
retrieval of path/filename of java files.

The code that i have written, successfully retrieves the filenames/path of the xml or manifest files,
but is unable to retrieve the path of the Java files in the packages.

the code I have used is :-

if (selection instanceof IStructuredSelection)

```
    {
        Object o = ((IStructuredSelection) selection).getFirstElement();
        if (o instanceof IFile) 
        {
            IPath loc = ((IFile) o).getLocation();
            if (loc != null) 
            {
                    selectedFile = loc.toOSString();

            }
            else
                selectedFile = "Error at loc";
        }
        else
            selectedFile = "Error at O";
    }
```

please help me in this, asap.
anxiously waiting.
thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your help I was able to figure out a sloution:

```
Object o =  ((IStructuredSelection) selection).getFirstElement();
```

then

```
IPath loc = ((ICompilationUnit) o).getPath();
```

then

```
selectedFile = loc.toOSString();
```

With this, you will be able to get the path of the java file that you selected. and also, this shows the pathname starting from the project name.

Comment: If you have a new/additional question, please ask a new question. This is not a forum.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than tell you a complete solution, I will show you how to find it...

1. Place a break point on "if (o instanceof IFile)" line.
2. Run in debug mode.
3. Select a Java file.
4. Use the debugger's variables view to examine variable "o".
5. Determine the type that the debugger shows for this variable.
6. Lookup the source of this type and check its API.

I am confident that if you follow these steps, you will arrive at a solution.

Comment: i must say that i am new at this eclipse thing,. was told to develop project on a software that i have never used.. i only know java/c++/c languages.  i am now stuck at step 4, 5. dont really understand, what u want me to do... sorry :(

Comment: please help me in, finding a solution for my query as soon as possible. i m stuck with lots more to add in this plugin, and i have very little time. plz help.

Comment: what do u mean by step 5... please explain.

Comment: In "Variables" view that's part of Eclipse debugger, there are two columns "Name" and "Value". Find variable "o" in the name column and see what is in the value column. Often it will be the type. If it isn't a type, but rather some kind of a toString() representation, right-click on the row and select "Open Declared Ty pe".

Comment: Come on... At least try to help yourself. You will get more respect and more people interesting in helping you if you can show that you are doing something to try to figure out the problem... Once you know the type, start examining its API... CompilationUnit implements ICompilationUnit which extends IJavaElement which has methods like getPath() and getResource().

Comment: yes this much i wrote, bt since i m using a WorkbenchWindowActionDelegate, i am confused. how to use the selection service, along with ICompilationUnit and such. thankqq..

Comment: Your question is asking how to get path/ifile. You have that already. If you need further help figuring out what to do, you should ask a separate question and provide details as to what you are trying to do and exactly what is unclear.

Comment: hi there, thanx for that. i guess i was being too much demanding. anyways. i figured a part of it out. the object O is an instance of ICompilationUnit, and nw i want to retrieve the IJavaElements out of it.. since its ICompilationUnit, i can only use findElements, right ?? if so, what should be the arguments for the findElements(arg list)  , answer back please.