# How to get the fullpath/name of the java file that i selected from the package explorer?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [cannot retrieve the selected java filename/path in eclipse plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9954294/cannot-retrieve-the-selected-java-filename-path-in-eclipse-plugin)
>   [I want to retrieve the path/filename of the selected java file from the package explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9975186/i-want-to-retrieve-the-path-filename-of-the-selected-java-file-from-the-package)

I am developing a plugin that requires retrieval of path/filename of java files.
I am using `WorkbenchWindowActionDelegate`.

The code that I have written successfully retrieves the filenames/path of the xml or manifest files (or any other format for that matter), but is unable to retrieve the path of the Java files in the packages.

The code I have used is :-

```
if (selection instanceof IStructuredSelection)
{
    Object o = ((IStructuredSelection) selection).getFirstElement();
    if (o instanceof IFile) 
    {
        IPath loc = ((IFile) o).getLocation();
        if (loc != null) 
        {
                selectedFile = loc.toOSString();
        }
        else
            selectedFile = "Error at loc";
    }
    else
        selectedFile = "Error at O";
}
```

When i select a Java file and press the plugin button, it displays `ERROR AT O`.